# Having an issue whilst saving JPEG, from html5 canvas, to server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, base64

I have an image loaded to the browser in a HTML canvas wrapper.

```
<canvas id="image1" class="" width="213" height="213" style="width: 213px; height: 213px;"></canvas>
```

When I try to save this to the server via AJAX, it works fine but when the file is a JPEG, it doesn't redirect from the AJAX.

Here's my ajax

```
var imageName = $('#image_name').val();
var canvas = document.getElementById('image1');

var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();       
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script.php",
    data: { 
            imgBase64: dataURL                          
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
       window.location.replace("http://****.co.uk/dither/step3.php?id="+data)
    });
```

Here's my php

```
<?php
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/');
$img = $_POST['imgBase64'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
echo $file;
?>
```

If the image is a png file, then the redirect works, but if it's a JPEG it just returns back to the same page.

If I alert the 'dataURL' before the ajax call it returns a array with the first part as 'data:image/png;base64' no matter what type of file extension.

I don't know enough about the base64 stuff to figure this out.

Comment: The file extension won't change the file type. It will still be a PNG even if you call it `foo.jpg`

Comment: its a different image and different file type, i think it may be related to the filesize

Comment: Well, it's hard for us to help you if you don't show us the code that fails. The above just saves a png, and not a jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as javascript is asynchronous the ajax was firing before the file upload had completed an thats why it was failing.

Comment: Looking at your current code, this answer doesn't really make sense since it is the ajax that actually is uploading the file? The `done()`-promise isn't executed until the request is all done.

Answer (score -1):

Use this sample of code to create create image from string, this will fix the issue

```
imagecreatefromstring($n) then imagejpeg($r,$y) or imagepng($r,$y);
```

and

```
imagedestroy($r);
```